# Java: DriverManager & MySQL port

Tags: java, mysql, xampp, database-connection

I'm using a java program to connect to a database created using PhpMyAdmin. 
I'm using XAMPP to open mysql port: 3306.
Of course when it's closed I can't connect to the database anymore through my java program. I use the following line code to get connection.

```
 con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/"+user,root,pwd);
```

Is there another way to connect to a database by providing for example it's full path without having to specify the mysql port and have it running? Or are there any java classes that help to get mysql port running without using softwares as XAMPP or EasyPHP ?

Comment: I think you misunderstand the processes involved. MySQL is one process. Java is another process.

Comment: Check out [H2DB](http://www.h2database.com/html/main.html). That can be embedded into a Java application, and provides quite nice features... Not exactly MySQL though.

Comment: OK thanks for these answers, I'll check for H2DB.